# How to solve elastic error of "Readiness probe failed: Error: Got HTTP code 503 but expected a 200" in GKE?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I am installing Elastic on GKE with the helm chart [here](https://://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/main/kibana). But after running this command `helm upgrade kibana elastic/kibana --values kibana.yaml`, it runs successfully but the pod gives this error `Readiness probe failed: Error: Got HTTP code 503 but expected a 200` in events.

The values file is shown thus:

```
elasticsearchHosts: "https://security-master:9200"

extraEnvs:
  - name: 'ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME'
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: elastic-credentials
        key: username
  - name: 'ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD'
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: elastic-credentials
        key: password
  - name: 'KIBANA_ENCRYPTION_KEY'
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: kibana
        key: encryptionkey

kibanaConfig:
  kibana.yml: |
    server.ssl:
      enabled: true
      key: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/elastic-certificate.pem
      certificate: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/elastic-certificate.pem
    xpack.security.encryptionKey: ${KIBANA_ENCRYPTION_KEY}
    xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey: ${KIBANA_ENCRYPTION_KEY}
    elasticsearch.ssl:
      certificateAuthorities: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/elastic-certificate.pem
      verificationMode: certificate
    xpack.security.authProviders: [saml]
    server.xsrf.whitelist: [/api/security/v1/saml]

protocol: https

secretMounts:
  - name: elastic-certificate-pem
    secretName: elastic-certificate-pem
    path: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  loadBalancerIP: ""
  port: 5601
  nodePort: ""
  labels: {}
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"https": "HTTPS"}'
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "kibana-backendconfig"}'
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    []
  httpPortName: http

readinessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 3
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 5

healthCheckPath: /api/status
```

I am wondering what might be the issue - could someone advice on how I could avoid this error entirely, thanks!